# How to use splint under linux with mingw

Tags: c, linux, mingw, mingw-w64, splint

I run debian linux actual stable with splint and mingw installed.
I want to check my c code (which I need to compile with mingw, sorry) by splint. Simply adding the mingw-includes is not enough to run. I tried with defining **GNU** and i686 - but I'm sure more is needed. What further do I have to define or include?

I tried the idea from **loan** resulting in a problem with `__builtin_va_list`.

```
Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2009
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/vadefs.h:24:43: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __builtin_va_list :
    int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

The funny thing is, that I can not find any definition for not - even with a recursive grep on the include folders. Am I searching wrong?
By defining it the way `-D__builtin_va_list=va_list` (from **benjarobin**) I ran into the error

```
Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2009

/home/ebelingb/.splintrc:229:1: Setting -stats redundant with current value
/home/ebelingb/.splintrc:229:1: Setting -showsummary redundant with current
                                   value

/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winnt.h:2390:15:
    Parse Error. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

which could not be recovered even by +trytorecover.

The lines from winnt.h (and neighbouring) reads

```
2388    typedef struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS {
2389      PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord;
2390      PCONTEXT ContextRecord;
2391    } EXCEPTION_POINTERS,*PEXCEPTION_POINTERS;
```

Strange, isn't it?

Okay as this thread gets no further answers, I'll give some motivation by this ***minimal not working example***:
Given a file `test.c`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LOGFILEFORMAT "C:\\CBM\\log\\%Y%m%d.log"
#define LOGTIMESTAMPFORMAT "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
int main() /*int argc,char **argv*/{
Sleep(1234);
    return (0);
}
```

and my `.splintrc`

```
-I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6/include
-I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6/include-fixed
-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include
```

the easy command `splint test.c` fails:

```
Splint 3.1.2 --- 20 Feb 2009

/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/_mingw.h:480:29: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __int64 :
    long int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.
```

Again I do not know, how to setup. The includes above result from a preprocesing call of the compiler `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`, which runs fine on `test.c`.

Comment: Splint is not using mingw or any compiler. Splint usage is like any compiler : `splint main.c`.

What are the errors ?

Comment: @benjarobin - of course I know that - but each compiler brings its own defines and so on. Thus you need to tell those defines and includes to splint.

Comment: What specific error do you get without using that `va_list` define?

Comment: @loan - I inserted the error output into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a good list of preprocessor defines using a blank C source file and running it through GCC/MinGW with your desired custom arguments:

```
gcc -E -P -v -dD [optional arguments] blank.c
```

Be sure to use the proper compiler for your target. You can redirect the output to a file and pass whatever defines you may need from there to splint.

Comment: This is for sure a great hint. Thank you. So sad - one error remains: `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/vadefs.h:24:43: Parse Error:
    Suspect missing struct or union keyword: __builtin_va_list :
    int. (For help on parse errors, see splint -help parseerrors.)
*** Cannot continue.` I do not know, how to resolve that problem.

Comment: Add `-D__builtin_va_list=va_list` ?

Comment: I tried that already - only resulting in another error. I'll edit the post to show that up.